# jQuery Auto Suggestion

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

i am working with a jquery Auto suggestion search programm.
anyone know jQuery auto suggestion like this http://www.last.fm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/a_fancy_apple.com-style_search_suggestion.html

Answer (score 3):

jQuery UI has a great Autocomplete-feature.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

I guess you could edit the code if you'd like too. I am pretty sure no plugins are exactly like last.fm's. You'll have to do some work yourself.